# Call Python function/script within Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, ajax

I have my beautiful JS/HTML/CSS. On my HTML file, I have a chat, and to interact with the user, the JavaScript file is useful.

The JavaScript file (part of) looks like :

```
$(".mytext").on("keyup", function(e){
    if (e.which == 13){
        var text = $(this).val();
        if (text !== ""){
            insertChat("you", text);              
            $(this).val('');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "test.py"
            });    
        }
    }
});
```

The error I get is on the HTML console, in French :

```
Erreur d’analyse XML : mal formé
Emplacement : http://localhost/test/test.py
Numéro de ligne 1, Colonne 2
```

so in English:

```
Error of XML analysis : malformed
Path : http://localhost/test/test.py
Line 1, column 2
```

I'm working within a XAMPP (Apache) server, and the visibility on my Python file looks OK. I heard about CGI or Flask, but it looks like you need to run those files before you go on your HTML file. I just want to call a function of my python file (or to call my python file, it's the same in my case).

I wanted to know if :

1. I can run Python file/functions on this way
2. I **absolutely** need to use Flask or CGI (and to run the Python file before ?)

Comment: You need to configure your server to run Python scripts through CGI.

Comment: It means I need to add the CGI thing into my Python file ? If yes, I need to run first my Python file, and in second the HTML File ? 
Thanks @Barmar

Comment: It means you need to configure your server so that it knows how to run Python scripts.

Comment: I'm lost, lol. I never used HTML or Server things before. Anyway, i'll Google your idea. Thanks (but if you have any other ideas or helps...) @Barmar